# can only concatenate list (not "str") to list

Tags: python, python-3.x

Olá, sou novo em python e programação provavelmente estou com um problema que deve ser bem conceitual.Fiz esse código para ler uma sequencia numérica em um txt e renomeá-lo com a sequência encontrada.

```
name_files3 = os.listdir(path_txt)

for TXT in name_files3:
    with open(path_txt + '\\' + TXT, "r") as content:
        search = re.search(r'(?:\d(?:[\s,.\-\xAD_]|(?:\\r)|(?:\\n))*){17}', content.read())
    if search is not None:
        name3 = search.group(0)
        # name3 = name3.replace("\n", "")
        # name3 = name3.replace("-", "")
        # name3 = name3.replace("\\", "")
        # name3 = name3.replace(".", "")
        # name3 = name3.replace(".", "")
        # name3 = name3.replace("/", "")
        # name3 = name3.replace(" ", "")
        fp = os.path.join("17_digitos", [letter for letter in name3 if letter.isdigit()] + "_%d.txt")
        postfix = 0
        while os.path.exists(fp % postfix):
            postfix += 1
        os.rename(
            os.path.join(path_txt, TXT),
            fp % postfix
        )
```

A principio eu estava usando a função `replace` remover todos os caracteres que apareciam entre números antes de renomear.  Acontece que existem caracteres no unicode que "parecem" hífen mas não são, então na hora de renomear alguns casos ele não estava funcionando. Então usei `[letter for letter in name3 if letter.isdigit()]` pra só pegar os números que aparecem.
Ele retorna esse erro:

```
    fp = os.path.join("17_digitos", [letter for letter in name3 if letter.isdigit()] + "_%d.txt")
TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list
```

tentei transformar name3 em string e não resolveu muito

Comment: O seu arquivo de texto possui somente 1 linha? A que contém o texto que servirá para renomear o arquivo.

Comment: @Marlysson o txt tem muitas linhas de texto, o script encontra no meio desse texto as sequencias numéricas que eu preciso.

Comment: Seria todos os números? Obtê-los e juntá-los em uma única string que seria o nome do arquivo..é isso?

Comment: Sim, o numero eu já estou conseguindo retirar do texto, inclusive estava conseguindo renomear sem problemas desse modo: 

"fp = os.path.join("17_digitos", name3 + "_%d.txt")"

mas acontece que eu nao tava conseguindo tirar todos os caracteres entre os numeros com a função replace, por isso resolvi alterar até pra tentar melhorar o código e nao precisar usar esse monte de replace

Comment: Tentou usar regex no próprio name3 assim: re.sub(r"\D","",name3) , com isso removerá tudo que não for número da string.

Comment: deu muito certo, obrigado!!

Comment: Vou colocar a ela como resposta aí vc a confirma, para caso outra pessoa tenha o mesmo problema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usa regex no próprio `name3` assim:

```
re.sub(r"\D","",name3)
```

Com isso removerá tudo que não for número da string.